# Is it possible to create ticker application on tizen tv web project?

Tags: tizen, samsung-smart-tv, tizen-web-app, tizen-web-simulator

I was created one ticker application for Samsung smart TV.Now i want to create the same ticker application for Samsung Tizen TV.ow my question is that Is it possible to create ticker application on Samsung Tizen TV web project? I was read in Samsung forum some of said it is possible and some of said it is not possible. If it is not possible so any other alternate way to do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Ticker apps are no longer supported on Tizen TVs.

While it will work when you are running in dev mode, it will fail when you try to submit the app to QA.  If you look in the [Samsung Seller Office > Support > Guide > Updated pre-test check list](http://seller.samsungapps.com/tv/assistance/guide#%20%22Seller%20Office%20%3E%20Support%20%3E%20Guid), you will see that apps with the ticker tag in the config.xml will fail in "Pre-Test", so those apps will not be permitted to be distributed through the SmartHub App Store.

The 'Ticker' setting used to serve the following two purposes:

1. Allow your app to have a transparent background so it could be
   displayed over the broadcast signal.
2. Allow your app to auto start if the user sets it up in the config.

As far as I've been able to determine, there are no mechanisms to get the comparable behaviors on 2015 model TVs.  ***For 2016 models only,*** you can do the following:

- *Transparency:* you will need to implement [Overlay PIP with HTML](https://www.samsungdforum.com/TizenGuide/tizen4631/index.html)
- *Auto-start:* if the TV has "Samsung Instant On" setting enabled, all apps which are running when the TV is turned "off" will be resumed when it is turned back "on".  The app will not be resumed if the TV is truly powered down. Take a look at [Multitasking](https://www.samsungdforum.com/TizenGuide/tizen51/index.html) and [Prelaunching](https://www.samsungdforum.com/TizenGuide/tizen4091/index.html) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If i want to develop application with ticker its not working anymore right. you said transparent background work with ticker app. so now my question is that is it possible to show 100 X 100 area bottom right corner and else part will be transparent so is it supported or not?

Comment: It is possible only on 2016 models with the "Overlay PIP with HTML", but it will put a very heavy burden on your app to manage all of the channel/volume changes, including the associated UI (that includes the 'channel list' and 'channel guide'). Also, using the TV Channel API to change the channels appears to only work for "Over The Air" broadcasts.  We have not been able to make the new remote work with cable/satellite input signals.  Also your overlay will not be present while other apps are running.  Just some of the bumps we hit when going down this path.